# Making python ignore indents in simple mathematical equation laid down on multiple lines with indents

Tags: python

I have a weird complex mathematical formula which I indented for better understanding look as follows:

```
EIET = IET
       + (TLBHR * {(1-PFR) * (TLBT + MAT)
                   + PFR   * (TLBT + MAT + PFT)
                  }
         )
       + (TLBMR * {(1-PFR) * (TLBT + MAT * (NPT + 1))
                   + PFR   * (TLBT + MAT * (NPT + 1) + PFT)
                  }
         )
```

Then I ran it only to realize that it resulted in unexpected indent. How can I keep these indents for better understanding of equation and still execute it in python without giving indentation error?

Answer (score 6):

The preferred method according to PEP-8 is to wrap the whole thing in brackets.

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied
>   line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines
>   can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in
>   parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash
>   for line continuation.
>
> Backslashes may still be appropriate at times. For example, long,
>   multiple with-statements cannot use implicit continuation, so
>   backslashes are acceptable:

[source](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length)

Also, you can't use braces `{}` as brackets. Use brackets instead `()`

```
EIET = (IET
       + (TLBHR * ((1-PFR) * (TLBT + MAT)
                   + PFR   * (TLBT + MAT + PFT)
                  )
         )
       + (TLBMR * ((1-PFR) * (TLBT + MAT * (NPT + 1))
                   + PFR   * (TLBT + MAT * (NPT + 1) + PFT)
                  )
         ))
```

Comment: I find this much better solution then adding backslashes.

Answer (score 3):

Just add an `\` at end of line:

```py
EIET = IET \
       + (TLBHR * {(1-PFR) * (TLBT + MAT) \
                   + PFR   * (TLBT + MAT + PFT) \
                  } \
         ) \
       + (TLBMR * {(1-PFR) * (TLBT + MAT * (NPT + 1)) \
                   + PFR   * (TLBT + MAT * (NPT + 1) + PFT) \
                  } \
         )
```

PS: you cannot use `{` in math operations in python, just change them to `(` and `)` :

```py
EIET = IET \
       + (TLBHR * ((1-PFR) * (TLBT + MAT) \
                   + PFR   * (TLBT + MAT + PFT) \
                  ) \
         ) \
       + (TLBMR * ((1-PFR) * (TLBT + MAT * (NPT + 1)) \
                   + PFR   * (TLBT + MAT * (NPT + 1) + PFT) \
                  ) \
         )
```

Comment: Ohh those indent errors gone. But seems that I cannot use brackets `{}` in equations???!!! It is giving me error: `unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'set'`. Is it interpreting `{}` as set?

Comment: @anir No, you can't use `{}` for grouping. Just use `()`